# Compare length of value contained in an array and get the greater value

Tags: php, arrays

I need to grab a strlen of a value contained in an array after comparision

```
like $a = ['0000', '00', '000000'];
```

so the greater length is 6 which is a[2] or '000000'

First compare the length of each value and and grab the greater one.

The code i am using is

```
function getzeros(){
  $val = explode('1',100101);
  foreach($val as $key => $value){
    if($value != '')
        I think some logic will come here....   
  }
}
getzeros();
```

Comment: I think this is what you want <?php

$a = ['0000', '00', '000000'];
echo "The long string length is  " .max(array_map('strlen',$a));

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
<?php $a = ['0000', '00', '000000']; 
echo "The long string length is " .max(array_map('strlen',$a)); 
?>
```

Comment: Yes that is correct ,  
It works but i also need to know if i also wants to take all 0s length which are between 1s like 1001 will give me 00 length =2 and and 1000100 then it will give me 000 length of three but i dont wants the value which is not between 1s so in 1000100 the last two zeros will not give any result

Comment: please check this code result, if last array value is not ' ' empty it means i have to neglect the last value....as in this case the last array value is 00 and is not between 1s , so i need to compare all previous values not this one.

Comment: function getzeros(){
 $val = explode('1',10010000100);
 var_dump($val);
 $finalval = max(array_map('strlen',$val));
return $finalval;
}

echo getzeros();

Comment: explode will not work on that manner . i think you need some regular expression to match the pattern .

Comment: No dear I think there is no need for regular expression , i will check the last element of the array and code it like this and finally got my desired solution

Comment: function getzeros(){
 $val = explode('1',100101000);
 $lastEl = array_values(array_slice($val, -1))[0];

 if($lastEl != '')
  array_pop($val);

 $finalval = max(array_map('strlen',$val));
return $finalval;
}

echo getzeros();

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = ['0000', '00', '000000'];
$b = [];
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    array_push($b, strlen($value));
}
$maxKey = max(array_keys($b));
echo $a[$maxKey];
```

Comment: I dont wants the max key value , i wants to the max length of a value, so the max length value may be on 0 or 1 or 2  so i need the max value dynamically.

Comment: That is $maxKey. Just `echo $maxKey;`

Comment: @GuanapadoPado Then just use echo $maxKey;

Comment: please see the solution of @JYoThI , That  is the one that i wants

Comment: Dear it is really the same what i wants ..... the solution you are providing is very simple but what i asked was really complex one.So please read my description again and i have also posted my final solution code so you can test it and see the result....

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for something like this:

```
<?php

$a = ['0000', '000000', '000'];

function getzeros($val) {
  $highest = 0;
  $position = 0;
  $answer = '';
  foreach($val as $key => $value){
    if($value != '') {
        if (strlen($value) > $highest) {
            $answer = $value;
            $highest = strlen($value);
            $position = $key;
        }
    }
  }
  echo "The longest string was '" . $answer . "', with a length of " . strlen($answer) . ", at index " . $position;
  // The longest string was '000000', with a length of 6, at index 1
}

getzeros($a);
```

This returns the longest string in the array `$a`, and also returns its index. The key here is setting an initial `$highest` variable to keep track of the highest `strlen()`, and then overwriting this value during the loop whenever an element in the array has a higher `strlen()`.

I've created an 3v4l demonstrating this **[here](https://3v4l.org/48Vac)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I would probably make the function like this and return the values from the function so that they can be used in the main program. https://3v4l.org/42RWn

Comment: what if the value is this $a = ['0000', '000000', '000'];

Comment: It is returning 000 as the largest value

Comment: @GuanapadoPado -- A slight oversight on my part. I forgot that you needed to set a new variable, rather than just use `$value` directly. You can't use it as it is still being processed in the loop. I've updated my answer to correct this, and it will now also work with the array `$a = ['0000', '000000', '000'];` :)

Comment: When dealing with falsey strings, doing a loose comparison on `$value` is ill-advised.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could also use `usort()` to get it working:

```
$arr = explode('1',100101000010);

usort($arr,function($a,$b) {
    return (strlen($a) <= strlen($b));
});

print_r($arr[0]);
```

The sorting gives you this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0000
    [1] => 00
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 
)
```

Then the `$arr[0]` ends up being `0000`;

Comment: It works but i also need to know if i also wants to take all 0s length which are between 1s like 1001 will give me 00 length =2 and and 1000100 then it will give me 000 length of three but i dont wants the value which is not between 1s so in 1000100 the last two zeros will not give any result